# Re-raising an exception in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a groovy-script with a try-catch statement. Now I would like to re-raise the exception, so that the caller can also react to that exception. Is there a canonical way to do this?

Comment: Any example code of what you've got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An example of what you have would be nice...

But do you mean something like:

```
Transaction tx = startTransaction()
try {
    tx.doSomething()
    tx.commit()
}
catch(ex) {
    tx.rollback()
    throw new MyTransactionFailedException("rolling back", ex)
}
```

Comment: I dislike rethrowing the same caught exception in this specific case (which I realize is *your* case, not the OP's). If you are catching a bunch of different exception types and immediately rethrowing some of them, that seems legit. However, If you are doing some processing inside the catch block (as in this case), i think it improves the debugability of code to wrap the exception in a new exception and throw that instead. Otherwise, the fact that the rollback happened during the stack unwinding would likely be lost in the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Re-throw the instance you just caught:

```
Transaction tx = startTransaction()
try {
    tx.doSomething()
    tx.commit()
}
catch(ex) {
    tx.rollback()
    throw ex
}
```